# Windows File Explorer Icon is wrong in Task Manager

Tags: windows-explorer, icons, windows-11, task-manager, cache

For some reason my Windows 11 File Explorer Icon is wrong in task manager, I tried rebuilding the cache and repair install, deleted all IconCache_x files and still the same.

Please note that I used an app called Blackbird to block all MS telemetry, and created a custom Powershell script to block all the telemetry and data collection and customize Windows [Also used WinAero Tweaker]

Can you please let me know where Windows store Task Manager Icons database?

Explorer.exe is not infected according to [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/9fbb6be6525fa388b76b08ea17c5c26d6b14e2a8b79b04d4802cb503fdc9339d/details) & officially signed by Microsoft

[This is the Task Manager screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZeDL.png)

Comment: Is the icon only changed in Task Manager, or is the Task Bar and the file at C:\Windows\explorer.exe affected as well?

Comment: Task bar & C:\Windows\explorer.exe are fine, only task manager icon is wrong.